# Handling two handlers for the same signal

Tags: signals

Would like to know if there are no issues if you change the handler within the current handler handling the sigalrm signal.

The scenario is - we have two handler h1, h2.
By default -  handler h1 is assigned to handle SIGALRM signal.
Is it ok to change the handler with h1 to h2 using sigaction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in registering new action for signal. New signal action will be consider by kernel when it will receive further request to serve signal. As far as this is not a problem for you it is OK to change the signal action from h1 to h2.